# Right-clicking files and folders inside SkyDrive folder hangs/freezes the file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-8.1, onedrive

Right-clicking individual files or folders causes the file explorer for the directory to hang for 30 seconds after which the context menu finally appears.

This happens only when right-clicking individual files or folders that are available offline. Interestingly, it does not happen when right-clicking with multiple files or folders selected, or files only available online. Right-clicking on the SkyDrive directory itself, or the empty space (to access sorting options, etc) does not cause any problems.

I was hoping to take advantage of the SkyDrive integration in Windows 8.1, and this issue is what's preventing me from jumping in completely. I'd be grateful for a resolution, but I wouldn't mind if others could comment on whether they can reproduce this issue.

Comment: run procmon in background and look at the duration column what was so slow: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor

Comment: Sounds like a context menu entry (that's only valid/shown for indiviual files) is screwing with things.  Does it act the same way in [Safe Mode](http://www.howtogeek.com/107511/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by deleting the SkyDriveEx entry in the registry at HKCR/*/shellex/contextmenuhandlers

that worked for files. Then for folders I deleted the SkyDriveEx entry at HKCR/Directory/shellex/contextmenuhandlers